# How to save full instances of Activities and hence prevent reloading for each start?

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, instance, drawer

My Android app essentially converts a website to a mobile application. The design is as follows:

- Navigation Drawer containing the different categories of posts as per the         website.
- Each option is a different activity. I designed a BaseActivity (with the Navigation Drawer initialisations) from which the other activities extend, so each activity has the Navigation Drawer. (I do not use fragments)
- Each activity calls a JSON parser to load posts from the website and hence takes upto 5 seconds to load.

The problem is that activities/screens once opened do not stay in the memory when called another time.

For example: Home Screen --> Category 1 Screen --> Home Screen causes the Home Screen to load a second time and hence takes up an additional 5 seconds.

How can I keep the full (or at least partial) instance of at least 3 activities in memory to avoid this nuisance?

I do call super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) but each activity restarts from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example: Home Screen --> Category 1 Screen --> Home Screen causes the Home Screen to load a second time and hence takes up an additional 5 seconds.

Add appropriate flags to your `Intent`, such as `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR__TOP`, when going back to the "Home Screen" activity. Among other things, this will bring the existing "Home Screen" instance back to the foreground, rather than creating a new one.

> How can I keep the full (or at least partial) instance of at least 3 activities in memory to avoid this nuisance?

Your problem is not whether they are in memory. If the user visited them before, they are already in memory. However, without flags on the `Intent` or attributes in the manifest to help control matters, each `startActivity()` call creates a new instance of the activity.

So, first, you need to decide what the navigational flow of your app will be, particularly in terms of the BACK button, to decide what existing activity instances can be reused.

Second, you need a more effective caching strategy, rather than just storing stuff in individual activities. That way, even if you do wind up creating new activity instances (to keep the BACK button flow the way you want), those activities can retrieve the data from a cache, rather than have to reload the data from the Web site.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had no knowledge of flags and how useful they are. This opens up a lot haha. And just in case anybody was wondering, I used the "FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT" flag.